# Загрузить библиотеку в апк из assets/res

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли загрузить разделяемую библиотеку с помощью `System.load` из папки assets или же res?
Если да, то как это должно выглядеть?

```
System.load("file:///android_asset/libmy.so");
```

К сожалению не работает

Comment: А зачем она у вас в ассетах, а не в положенном для неё месте? Как минимум нужно  записать её в обычный файл: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434262/15923106. Но со времён того ответа в ОС произошли изменения и возможно так уже не получится. Где-то на гитхабе была библиотека для решения подобных задач и обхода багов загрузки библиотек в отдельных версиях ОС, но я не помню её название

Comment: Кладем в app/src/main/jniLibs/ в соответствующие архитектурам папочки (arm64-v8a и тп), и грузим с помощью `System.loadLibrary("my")`.